# Unblocking blocked filepath in Windows

Tags: windows, path

I am trying to access .lua scripts from a mod for a computer game.
The mod came as a .zip file with the scripts folder invisible.
After extracting the scriptsfolder is still not visible.

The scripts are located in the main folder in the subfolder \scripts and are readable to the game.

[As you can see, the path /vehicles is visible and in the same structure as /scripts, which is not accesseble.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnyXu.png)

If anyone wants to take a look for themselves, here is the link to the mod in question:
https://www.farming-simulator.com/mod.php?lang=en&country=gb&mod_id=238269&title=fs2022

I am hoping someone can help me get access to the scripts.

Kind regards

I have already tried:
Enabling "show hidden files" in the windows explorer
entering the path in the windows explorer manually
navigating to the folder with PowerShell

I always get the error:

> Path not found